# Browser Back Button on ajax call

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

When I log into my application the url of the application is `localhost/#`.

And then I made an search in my application where it goes with ajax call and after I get the results the url still remains same.

So, when I click on back button of browser my application is going back to the login page of my application. So I just need to restrict the page not to go to login page.

I am trying to do it this way:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
        history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
        window.history.go(1);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            window.history.go(-1);
            // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
            // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
        };
    }
    else {
        var ignoreHashChange = true;
        window.onhashchange = function () {
            if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                ignoreHashChange = true;
                window.location.hash = Math.random();
                // Detect and redirect change here
                // Works in older FF and IE9
                // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
                // delimiter on the end of the URL
            }
            else {
                ignoreHashChange = false;   
            }
        };
    }
```

But when I click on back button in my home page then the back button is getting disabled, instead I need to get the search results which I have performed earlier.